# Angular JS ng-change event is not firing up

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is my code example

```
<select ng-model="selectedProdTeam" 
    ng-options="team for team in prodTeams | orderBy" 
    ng-change="getRolesBasedOnSelectedTeamProd()">
    <option value="">Select Teams</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.getRolesBasedOnSelectedTeamProd = function(){
    if($scope.selectedProdTeam != null || $scope.selectedProdTeam !=undefined){ 
        $scope.prodRoles = $scope.prodResp.$scope.selectedProdTeam;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your html. The select element is missing a `>`.

Comment: Sorry...It was while posting in stackoverflow

Comment: Actually, even is not firing.

Answer (score 0):

It should be,

```
<select ng-model="selectedProdTeam" ng-options="team for team in prodTeams | orderBy" ng-change="getRolesBasedOnSelectedTeamProd()">
 <option value="">Select Teams</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT**:

Your orderBy filter should take a parameter or remove the filter.

```
ex | orderBy:'name'"
```

**`DEMO`**

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
   $scope.prodTeams = [
    { 'name':'Chelsea',
      'id':1
    },
    { 'name':'UK',
      'id':2
    }
   ];
   $scope.getRolesBasedOnSelectedTeamProd = function(){
    alert('fired');
   }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <select ng-model="selectedProdTeam" ng-options="team.name  for team in prodTeams | orderBy:'name'" ng-change="getRolesBasedOnSelectedTeamProd()">
     <option value="">Select Teams</option>
    </select>
 </body>
```

Comment: Please ignore the typo. It happened while posting to stack overflow

Comment: There is an actual issue.

Comment: your orderby should take a parameter. check the edit

Comment: check the demo attached

Comment: FYI. Order by works fine for other dropdowns which I am using. Let me check out on the events case.